# Looking for regex solution

Tags: regex, date

I need to find in text xx.xx.xxxx where x = any number from 0 to 9.
Anyone?

Comment: Please make an attempt to come up with a regex. This is one of the easiest regexes in existence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will be `[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}`

`[0-9]`stands for any integer in range 0 to 9, the number in curly brackets (`{2}` in this case) indicates how many times should the pattern be repeated.
You need to escape the dots with a backslash because otherwise they will be interpreted as any character.

Answer (score 0):

because you have not specify on whitch langage your are looking for, i assume is on javascript.

Just try this regex :

```
var matched = "Edit the Expression & Text to see matches. 01.02.2299 Roll over matches or the expression for details. PCRE & Javascript 01.02.2299".match(/\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}/g);
```

let split this regex by little peace :

`/\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}/g`

- first and last `/` is for regex separator.
- `g` is to set this regex as global, will catch all string who match on your original string.
- `\d` is to say any char who are between 0 and 9
- `{2}` means previous pattern should be repeat 2 times.
- `\.` is to specify i want to match dot char, by default, dot is joker who can represent any char.

I also highly recommand you to use https://regexr.com/ for testing your Regex. On tool section, you will have clear explication on each item who compose your regex. On the right you can fin any kind of "thing" who can be use on Regex.